# Finding netid in CIDR

Tags: networking, tcp, cidr

I am practicing questions related to CIDR and I have come across a particular question which I need some explanation. Can somebody please explain in detail how to answer this question.

An address space, allocated to a site via CIDR, extends from 110.45.232.0 to 110.45.233.255. What is the netid of the site network indicated by the prefix?

A = 110.45.232.0/21

B = 110.45.232.0/23

C = 110.45.2320/24

D = 110.45.233.0/24

Comment: Nothing to do with programming.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about IPv4 addressing and subnetting.